# Xamarin Custom ButtonRenderer Text under Image

Tags: button, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am trying to place Label under the image inside a button and center it. I have a custom renderer for the button but for some reason I can not produce the desired output. The code is in C# Xamarin.

---

XAML Code:

```
              <Controls:ExtendedButton   
                  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  x:Name="search"
                  Text="Search"   
                  Image="Completed.png"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading}"
                  Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                  WidthRequest ="120"
                  HeightRequest ="120"
                  TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                   >                    
            </Controls:ExtendedButton>
```

C# iOS CustomRenderer

```
     public class ExtendedButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    UIButton btn;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {

            btn = (UIButton)Control;



            CGRect imageFrame = btn.ImageView.Frame;
            imageFrame.Y = 0;
            imageFrame.X = (btn.Frame.Size.Width / 2) - (imageFrame.Size.Width / 2 );
            btn.ImageView.Frame = imageFrame;


            var labelSize = new NSString(btn.TitleLabel.Text).
               GetBoundingRect(
                   new CGSize(btn.Frame.Width, float.MaxValue),
                   NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                   new UIStringAttributes() { Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(8) },
                   null);

            CGRect titleLabelFrame = new CGRect(labelSize.X, labelSize.Y, labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height);
            titleLabelFrame.X = (btn.TitleLabel.Frame.Size.Width / 2) - (labelSize.Width / 2);
            titleLabelFrame.Y = (btn.ImageView.Frame.Y ) + (btn.ImageView.Frame.Size.Height) + 20;
            btn.TitleLabel.Frame = titleLabelFrame;


        }

    }
```

---

DesiredOutput

```
+-----------+
|           |
|  (Image)  |     
|   Label   |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 12):

Just FYI, and for future generations, `Xamarin.Forms` Button class support property `ContentLayout` now, with values: Top, Bottom, Left, Right (position of image). So for your desired output you can use native Button:

```
<Button   
 ContentLayout="Top"
 VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
 x:Name="search"
 Text="Search"   
 Image="Completed.png"
 IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading}"
 Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
 WidthRequest ="120"
 HeightRequest ="120"     
 TextColor="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

I couldn't remember where I found this information, but see [Button.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/17e2a4b94d5105b53c5875d9416d043f14313305/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Button.cs) and [ButtonRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/17e2a4b94d5105b53c5875d9416d043f14313305/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs)

Answer (score 2):

I would use fact that `UIButton` supports already supports an `UIImage` along with the `Title` text, you just need to adjust the `ImageEdgeInsets` and `TitleEdgeInsets` and set to the x/y alignments to center.

```
public class CenterImageButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public CenterImageButtonRenderer() { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center;
                Control.HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center;

                #if DEBUG
                // Set the border so we can see button bounds on a white background for testing alignment
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 5;
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
                #endif

                // The button image is not availabe due to lazy load, so we load "again", get the bounds and dispose of it... :-(
                var uiImage = UIImage.FromFile(((Button)e.NewElement).Image.File);
                var lineHeight = Control.TitleLabel.Font.LineHeight;
                Control.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(-lineHeight, uiImage.Size.Width + (uiImage.Size.Width / 2), 0, 0);
                Control.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(uiImage.Size.Height, -uiImage.Size.Width, 0, 0);
                uiImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So assuming:

```
var button = new CenterImageButton
{
    Text = "StackOverflow",
    Image = "so.png"
};
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Works Perfect. Just had to edit ImageEdgeInsets .Thanks a bunch. I really appreciate it.